# The Excel/VBA project does not work since changement of computer despite the fact that the option "ignore undeclared variables is enabled"?

Tags: vba, excel

I need the activation of "option explicit off".

I have an old Excel/VBA project in which variables are not declared before use. I know this is not a good practice but the project is old and useful.

I disable the check of undeclared variable in configuration of VBE.

In the new computer the problem persist and on the old one I never get this problem.

Both computer use office 2010.

Is there a other way to force compilation whith goal "option explicit off" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  Are you getting a specific error on a specific line of code?  Why not just declare your variables?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just comment out or just remove `Option Explicit`? .. there is also Comintern way " Why not just declare your variables?"

Answer (score 1):

You can allow for the implicit declaration of variables by disabling Option Explicit; that is, by changing `Option Explicit` in your code to `Option Explicit Off`.

This will allow you to compile without having dimensioned all of your variables.

If this does not solve your problem, we will need more information on the exact line of code your project is failing on. All the best, Dan.

Comment: if I put **Option Explicit Off** on the first line then I have 
Compilation error : Expected : end of statment

If I remove the word **of**, the compilation continue and I'm blocked on the next undeclared variable